# After Installation of canopy express

Tags: python, enthought, post-install, canopy

Hi I installed canopy express successfully and I can also work with it (coming from epd-free) ... however when I start it I get the following console message (Debian Linux - Lenny):

kampmann@primergy:~$ canopy
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)" 
kampmann@primergy:~$

what is "icu18u" (translation of the German text: "cannot open shared object-file - file not found")?

Comment: No idea about the `icu` part but the `i18n` bit is the usual shorthand for "internationalization", i.e., the code to handle English, German, French, Maori, etc., language translations.  Clearly some shared library is missing.

Comment: Also, Please tag your posts with the `enthought` tag for Enthought staff and other users to notice your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icui18n error is a harmless error.  Look at this [debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673537) for more details

Comment: Thanks punchagan and torek, so I can lean back in my chair and stay calm :)